# EM wave polarization check

Tags: wave, polarity, microwave

I am trying to recall the quick way to check the EM polarization theoretically, I mean if I have a wave described as (ssume capital letters are vectorial fields)

\begin{equation}
\ E = E_o *exp(j* \varphi)\\
\ E_o = E_r +j*E_i\\
\end{equation}

I recall that there were an easy math check to verify the kind of polarization that the EM wave had, however **I am not completely sure about whether the vector/cross products are as showed below or not**, could anyone remind me a bit?

Lineal polarization

\begin{equation}
\ \require {cancel} E_r = 0 \ or \ E_i= 0 \ \wedge \ \cancel {E_r \otimes E_i=0 } \
\end{equation}

Circular polarization
\begin{equation}
\ \mid E_r\mid =\mid E_i\mid \ \wedge \ \cancel { E_r\otimes E_i=1 } \
\end{equation}

Elliptical polarization
\begin{equation}
\  None \  of \   the\   conditions\   above
\end{equation}

Edited with **correct answer** given by simplicis veritatis, and a own example since thus I can remember it even better.

Lineal polarization

\begin{equation}
\ E_r = 0 \ or \ E_i= 0 \ \wedge \ E_r\centerdot E_i\neq0 \ 
\end{equation}

Circular polarization
\begin{equation}
\ \mid E_r\mid =\mid E_i\mid \ \wedge \ E_r\centerdot E_i=0 \
\end{equation}

Elliptical polarization
\begin{equation}
\  None \  of \   the\   conditions\   above
\end{equation}

Example
\begin{equation}
\ E = (\hat{x}+\hat{y}-j\hat{y} ) *exp(j* \varphi)\\
\ E_o = \hat{x}+\hat{y} +j*-\hat{y} = E_r +j*E_i\\
\ \mid E_r\mid = \sqrt{2} \\
\ \mid E_i\mid = 1 \\
\ \mid E_i\mid \neq \mid E_r\mid \\
\ E_r\centerdot E_i =1-j \neq 0 \Rightarrow Elliptical Polarization
\end{equation}

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we express the wave using two components:

1. The wave is linearly polarized, if the phase angles of the two components are equal.
   (parallel vectors)
2. The wave is circularly polarized, if phases are rotated by \$90^0\$ degrees with respect to each other and the  amplitudes are equal. (perpendicular vectors: zero dot product)
3. The wave is elliptically polarized, if phases are rotated by \$90^0\$ degrees with respect to each other and the  amplitudes are not equal.